# How can I change the OOB height/width of my silverlight application dynamically?

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser

I have a **silverlight** app which can be installed as an **out-of-browser** app by the user.

Every time I change the **height** and **width** of the application, I have to also:

- right-click on project
- properties
- click Out-of-Browser settings button
- change the height and width manually

**How can I change the defined height and width of the Out-of-Browser application in code?**

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
MyBlueForm = new MyBlueForm();

this.RootVisual = startupWindow;

this.MainWindow.Width = startupWindow.Width;
this.MainWindow.Height = startupWindow.Height;
}